# How do I make Wget name files as part of URL?

Tags: regex, sed, web-crawler, wget

**Short story:**

I want Wget to name downloaded files as they match regex token `([^/]*)`

```
wget -r --accept-regex="^.*/([^/]*)/$" $MYURL
```

**Full story:**

I use GNU Wget to recursively download one specific folder under particular WordPress website. I use regex to accept only posts and nothing else. Here is how I use it:

```
wget -r --accept-regex="^.*/([^/]*)/$" $MYURL
```

It works and Wget follows all the desired URLs. However, it saves files as `.../last_directory/index.html`, but I want these files to be saved as `last_directory.html` (`.html` part is optional).

Is there a way to do that with Wget alone? Or would you suggest how to do the same thing with `sed` or similar tools?

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed.

```
wget -r --accept-regex="^.*/([^/]*)/$" $MYURL |  sed 's~\(.*\)/[^.]*~\1~'
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '/foo/last_directory/index.html' | sed 's~\(.*\)/[^.]*~\1~'
/foo/last_directory.html
```

Comment: If I got it right, then you suggest to (1) download all the files, then (2) traverse all files with bash script and (3) apply the `sed` command to rename each file. Ideally, I would like to avoid traversing the files after the download.
Unfortunately, this method does not work well if the folder has extra files - I only want to rename the freshly downloaded ones. This script will move other files up one folder.